# Google Script Range Error - Owner Range?

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I've been playing around with Google Scripts and I'm trying to pull some data into a sheet. It all seems to check out except one line where I get a range error, I know (or I think I do) that it has something to do with the OwnerRange but this is a first time for me and I'm still trying to learn as I go.

```
  ownerSheet.clear();
  var ownerLen = ownerArray.length;
  var ownerRange =  "A1:C" + ownerLen;
  if (ownerLen > ownerSheet.getMaxRows()) {
    var addRows = ownerLen - ownerSheet.getMaxRows();
    ownerSheet.insertRowsAfter(ownerSheet.getMaxRows(), addRows);
  }  
  ownerSheet.getRange(ownerRange).setValues(ownerArray);
```

I've tried changing the "A1:C" but I get height errors when doing that. The columns that get generated in the sheet are from A to J. The original script is here: https://charlielove.org/?p=10117

Others there are having the same error it looks, with the same line. Thought I'd ask here just in case anyone can help.

Comment: @mark my answer I didn't no, when the script runs it creates a sheet in my Drive. I just tried changing 'idtoname' to my sheet name, same error.

Comment: While including a link to the complete script could be helpful, questions on this site should be self-contained. In other words, add a minimal, complete and verifiable example (the fewer code lines as possible to reproduce the problem).

Comment: We could provide a lot more assistance if you would provide a complete example.  It's kind of hard to get 1/2 of a function to do much of anything.

Answer (score -1):

You could try:

`ownerSheet.getRange(1,1,ownerArray.length,ownerArray[0].length).setValues(ownerArray);`